# Javascript: why doesn't this variable initialization take effect on numbers?

Tags: javascript

I want to initialize some public variables in Javascript, but it only works for Strings and not for numerals. Any reasons?

```
var Person = function(_name) {
    this._name = _name;
    this.__age = 20;
    this._occupation = "Javascript Programmer";
};

var person = new Person("Chandra");
console.log(person._age); // Prints undefined
console.log(person._name); // Prints Chandra correctly.
```

Is this because _age is a number and not "auto-boxed" to be a Number Object?

Comment: `this.__age` has two underscores.

Comment: No, `person._age` does not exist. Did you mean `person.__age`?

Comment: Dumbest question I have asked probably. Right.. __age was the culprit and not anything to do with objects.

Answer (score 5):

You have an extra underscore the first time.

```
this.__age = 20;
```

should be

```
this._age = 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just in a typo. On line 3, you say `this.__age = 20;`. There is an extra underscore, so you should have said `this._age = 20;`.

And AFAIK, JavaScript doesn't do any discrimination between objects. Everything (except null and undefined I guess) can be an object, and as long as you call it the right name, in the right scope, it will initialize like always. Further, the String and Number you create are actually a string and number primitives (note the lowercase). The number stays a number, not an Object, when you implicitly call toString().

http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/the-secret-life-of-javascript-primitives/